# Unable to install CPLEX on mac os 10.13.6

Tags: java, cplex, invocationtargetexception

When I execute CPLEX installation file, I get a popup with the following message: "This application has unexpectedly quit. Invocation of this Java Application has cause an InvocationTargetException. This application will now exit. (LAX)"

There is a button "Details" which gives more details on the error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.io.PrintWriter.println(java.lang.String)" because "this.b_" is null
      at com.zerog.ia.installer.IAStatusLog.addStatus(Unknown Source)
      at com.zerog.util.CheckDiskSpaceUtil.isEnoughDiskSpace(Unknown Source)
      at com.zerog.ia.installer.actions.CheckDiskSpace.isEnoughDiskSpace(Unknown Source)
      at com.zerog.ia.installer.actions.CheckDiskSpace.isEnoughDiskSpace(Unknown Source)
      at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgr.initPreInstall(Unknown Source)
      at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgr.initAAMgr(Unknown Source)
      at com.zerog.ia.installer.LifeCycleManager.a6(Unknown Source)
      at com.zerog.ia.installer.LifeCycleManager.executeApplication(Unknown Source)
      at com.zerog.ia.installer.Main.main(Unknown Source)
      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
      at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
      at com.zerog.lax.LAX.launch(Unknown Source)
      at com.zerog.lax.LAX.main(Unknown Source)
```

The only similar issue that I found was solved by disabling the dark mode ([link](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/ibm-ilog-cplex-optimization-studio-installer-has-silent-failure-mac-os-1015)). However, the stack error is not exactly the same and I am not using the dark mode.

This issue happens with both CPLEX installation files (i.e. with or without ARM).

I have no idea how to solve this and so any help would be welcome.